# How to build a non-binary tree (with dependencies) incrementally

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, dependencies

## Short Description

I need to build a non-binary tree (language doesn't matter for now, but preferably in C++) from a list of items that do have dependencies to each other, but non-recurring and not cyclic.

The data for the nodes are read from a file and incrementally inserted into the tree.
The troubling part is how to handle those nodes which do not have parent-nodes yet that fulfill the dependency of the inserted node.

## Detailed Description

### Rough Outline

The assignment is easy: represent a bunch of Tasks and Subtasks in a non-binary tree.
This assignment would be quite easy to understand and implement, if not for a tiny condition: the list of Tasks has to be generated incrementally, so do the nodes in the tree.

### Scenario

The Tasks are generated asynchronously and have to be added into the tree once the data to a certain Task is received.
This is "simulated" by reading a csv-file which has a certain Task in each line with some data, the most important ones being the PID and PPID attributes.

After a line is read and parsed, a Task is being created and inserted into the tree.
The tree should automatically resolve the dependencies following two simple rules:

1. Only show the node when the dependency is met (namely when a parent-node has been inserted before), but memorize the (now orphaned) node.
2. Whenever a Task(node) is added, check if it's a parentnode of one of the above meantioned orphaned ones and reconcile the nodes if rule #1 isn't infringed while doing so.

Please disregard the faulty logic behind this scenario: Normally, there can't be any SubTask without a ParentTask existing (at least in monolithic kernel designs).
And while the List of Tasks certainly do contain the ParentTasks needed to model the tree, it is unknown **when** the ParentNode-Data is read and inserted into the tree.

### Desired outcome

Below is a figure showing the "raw data", a list of (unsorted) Tasks which has been created incrementally while adding one Task after another to the list.
The tree represents the subset of Tasks which has been inserted so far:

[image: Figure showing the desired output]

Please keep in mind that the tree is completely "naked" until the Tasks with the PIDs 1, 2 and 3 are inserted, because the other nodes are dependent of them.

### What I did so far

I've written a Qt-C++ Code with three rough components:

- TaskTree which holds a Root-Node (a node without any task-data)
- TaskNode which has a field to hold the task-data and a *QList<TaskNode>* which is, in simple terms, a vector of TaskNodes to reference childnodes
- Task has the related attributes (like pid and ppid)

It is no problem to insert a TaskNode if the parentnode already exists.
This only works though in a perfect world, in which the Tasks are sorted upon their respective dependencies AND there's a determined amount of Tasks to be added.

I don't have to tell you that such a scenario is highly unlikely though, so the tree creation has to memorize any orphaned node (which is a node that doesn't have a parent yet, duh).

I've tackled this "memorization" in different ways, but failed alltogether because I couldn't wrap my head around the algorithms behind it.
The two most promising thoughts I had were these:

1. Insert every orphaned node into a vector. Upon inserting a parentnode, check if it has children in the Orphan-Vector and reconcile. Do this recursively for the newly created subtree to match all possiblities.
2. Assign the PPID to the tree's RootNode, being 0 for the most top one. When an orphaned node appears, create a new TaskTree, assign the PPID of the orphan to the newly created tree and add the orphan to it.
   This creates subtrees which can be quit intricate themselfs if several orphans match one of the trees. After each inserted Node, try to reconcile the subtrees to the root-tree.

Unfortunately I had to give up continuing those two concepts due to several spontaneous SIGSEGV's and other problems occuring because of the recursions etc.

---

So in the end I'm here trying to find a way to actually make this work without cutting down the complexicity of the problem through assumptions and other cheats...

Do you guys and gals have an idea which algorithm I could use for this problem or what category of problem this even is?

Comment: I am not sure if Stack Overflow is the right place for this question.  You might have better luck on [Computer Science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You could try placing all of the orphaned tasks as children of the root node. Then when a new node is added you check all of the tasks that are children of the root and move any that are children of the newly added node to their now added parent.

Comment: I would also suggest possibly posting another question focused around the specific errors you are getting and how to fix them.

Comment: It sounds like your first solution is a correct one and you've just got an issue in your code somewhere. Inserting the orphaned nodes into a holding space temporarily and then moving them from there when their parents are found is a completely valid way of doing this. There are alternatives which might be more efficient, but this is completely functional.

Comment: @NathanOliver when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 is the right one to take.  The pieces that you are missing are that you need an `unordered_map` called `node_needed` that maps as yet unseen parent nodes to a `vector` of child trees that are waiting for it.  You need a similar one mapping `node_seen` to the associated tree for nodes that have been seen.

Then when you see a node you perform the following:

```
Create TaskTree with only this node.
Add this TaskTree to the node_seen map

If this node's ID is in the parent_needed map:
    Add each tree in the parent_needed map to this tree
    Remove this node's ID from the parent_needed map

If this node has no parent:
    Add this node's tree to the root tree
Else if this node's parent ID is in the node_seen map:
    Add this node's tree to the parent tree
Else if this node's parent_ID is in the parent_needed map:
    Append this node's tree to the parent_needed vector
Else:
    Create a vector containing this node's tree
    Add a mapping from this node's parent ID to that vector in the parent_needed map
```

Assuming no bugs (HAH!  Bugs are part of life...), this should work.

Comment: This approach seems feasible, I'll try to implement it and will report back if it actually worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After some deliberate design changes, I've come up with - what I think - the easiest way to implement this:

```
InsertTask(Task newTask)
{
    Task parentTask = searchTreeForParent(newTask->ppid)
    If (parentTask not found)
    {
        parentTask = treeRootNode;
    }

    If (treeRootNode has children)
    {
        For (every children in treeRootNode: child)
        {
            If (child->ppid != treeRootNode->pid AND child->ppid == newTask->pid)
            {
                newTask->addChild(child)
                treeRootNode->remove(child)
            }
        }
    }

    parentTask->addChild(newTask)
}
```

The algorithm behind it is pretty easy: You add the new Tasks to the root node if there is no parent node yet and at the same time check if the newly added Task has potential children in the root node (because those orphaned ones were added to the root node before).

So if you actually insert all the Tasks to fulfill the dependencies, you end up with a complete and valid tree.
If you don't supply all the parent nodes, you end up with some of the branches being complete and valid and a bunch of orphaned ones in the root node.
But that's no problem because there is an easy trick to differenciate between a complete branch and orphans: just check if the ppid equals the root node's pid and voila, you output only those branches that are complete.